# Uncaught (in promise) -- How to find the source of the problem in a Deno program

Tags: exception, async-await, promise, deno

I'm having trouble with my Deno program. I'm getting messages like this:

```
error: Uncaught (in promise) Error: No such host is known. (os error 11001)
    at deno:core/01_core.js:106:46
    at unwrapOpResult (deno:core/01_core.js:126:13)
    at async Object.connect (deno:extensions/net/01_net.js:219:13)
```

Then deno exits.

**I don't know how to debug this.**  This stack trace only points to code that comes with Deno, not to my code.

I've searched my code and I've put a .catch() or a try/catch everywhere I can think of, but that did not help.

**Is there anything I can do to help me find the problem?**  I'd love it if I could get *a complete stack dump*.  Or if I could *have the debugger pause* at the problem.  Or if you have *any other suggestions*.

Thanks!

---

**Edit 8/29/2021**

I found two bugs in my code.  Here are the actual bugs.  It was a serious pain to track these down.  I'm **still looking for** a tool or process to help the next time I make a silly mistake like this.

Bug #1:
[image]
I was using try/catch (shown in red) when I should have been using .catch() (shown in green).  My try/catch did nothing.  If there was an error sending the data, that would cause my program to crash.

Bug #2:

```
const promise = Deno.connect(options);
promise.catch(reportError);
promise.then(longRunningTask);
await someOtherPromise;
promise.then(connection => {
  // We never get to here.
  try {
    connection.close();
  } catch {
    console.log("");
  }
});
// And we never get to here.
```

The code I've shown here was spread throughout a much longer program.  I did not understand the rules regarding promises.  The second .then() requires a second .catch().

Comment: This issue suggests that perhaps your host is redirecting to a relative URL: https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/6708

Comment: No.  This was TCP/IP, not HTTP.  I was not using fetch.  I was hosting a web server, accepting an HTTP connection, upgrading to an WebSocket, then using Deno.connect() in a loop to create several TCP/IP sockets.  The specific error message shown above came when I turned off my network to do some testing.  I knew the connection would fail because of that.  I'm trying to get it to fail gracefully.

Comment: I've not personally sought to do this yet but I suspect you can debug Deno's core JS code similar to how you can [debug your own code](https://deno.land/manual@v1.13.1/getting_started/debugging_your_code). You might need to do a [custom build](https://deno.land/manual/contributing/building_from_source) in order to debug but I would hope not but then you could make minor modifications to where you think things are going wrong and better troubleshoot/debug what's going on in [01_core.js](https://github.com/denoland/deno/blob/main/core/01_core.js).

Comment: Interesting.  I'll have to look into that.  Thanks @mfulton26

Comment: I suggest using `await` instead of `then` where possible. Doing such in `async` functions, etc. makes the code read more like synchronous code and works in conjunction with `try..catch` blocks, etc.

Comment: Agreed.  `await` seems to make more readable code.

Answer (score 0):

Here was one of my attempts to solve this problem.  I told VS code to **break on all exceptions**.  It seems to ignore my request.  I never got to a breakpoint, but the debug console shows that the program crashed because of an exception.

[image]